# Trying to ignore blank lines to parse the last occurrence of a string in a text file

Tags: c#, arrays, string, parsing

So I have this text file structured like:

```
Date: 12/23/23
.
.
.
Date: 12/23/66
.
.
Date: 12/25/67
```

For this, I am trying to get the last Occurrence of date, which is:

```
Date: 12/25/67
```

and with that, I already know how by this code:

```
string date = "";
foreach(string line in File.ReadAllLines("mytext.txt"))
{
    date = GetDate_value(line, date);    
}

public static string GetDate_value(string line, string date)
{ 
    if (line.Contains("Date:"))
    {
        date = line;   
    }

    string[] separatingStrings = { "Date: " };
    string[] str = date.Split(separatingStrings, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", str));
    return str.Last();
}
```

With this, when I return date, I get the last occurrence. However I am trying to parse it even further to where it just includes 12/25/67.

With that, I know how with the logic above. However, when I try to parse the file, I get an error, saying that the array in the element does not exist. Further examination shows with my `Console.WriteLine` of the array shows:

```
[]
[]
[]
[]
[  , 12/25/67]
[  , 12/25/67]
[  , 12/25/67]
[  , 12/25/67]
.
.(repeats for how many lines in text file)
```

I'm wondering how come I am getting no elements in the beginning section when everything should be:

```
[  , 12/25/67]
[  , 12/25/67]
[  , 12/25/67]
[  , 12/25/67]
```

I tried using this to replace the `foreach` line:

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadAllLines(file).Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)))
```

However it still does not ignore the last line. How would i make it so that it ignores the null elements in the beginning?

***EDIT***

So with this if statement in the Get date function:

```
string[] separatingStrings = { "Date: " };
string[] str = date.Split(separatingStrings, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if(str.Length == 0)
{

    Console.WriteLine("null");

}
```

I figured out these `values([])` were of length 0, with that, how would I be able to skip the length 0 arrays to ignore it ?

Comment: if you know the format, you can simply use Remove method of C# once yo get the line

Comment: Would you be able to explain it further please?

Comment: you are getting Date: 12/25/67 so you can remove the Date: from the string

Comment: this can help you `string str = File.ReadLines("test.txt").Where(s => s.Contains("Date:")).ToList().Last().Remove(6);`. you have to handle the `null` cases

Comment: Didn't you ask the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62368471/how-to-get-the-last-two-occurrences-of-the-same-string-in-a-text-file-c-sharp) already?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try doing this instead:

```
string last =
    File
        .ReadLines("mytext.txt")
        .Aggregate(
            (string)null,
            (a, x) =>
                x.StartsWith("Date: ")
                    ? x.Substring("Date: ".Length) 
                    : a)
```

If `last` is `null` then your text file did not contain a line starting with `"Date: "`, otherwise it'll contain the last date in the file (still as a string though).

I also chose `File.ReadLines` as this lazily reads the file so file size shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Im sorry I actually dont understand it, would I pass this in my foreach loop?

Comment: @thesenate42069 No, that code will replace your foreach loop. In last you will find your desired result. Thats why he said: *doing this **instead***

Comment: @thesenate42069 - Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. This code is all you need.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code snippet is the `GetDate_value` function, where you execute the same code whether the passed line contains `Date:` or not. You need to move everything to the `if` block to return the date otherwise the function should return `null` or `string.Empty`.

```cs
void TheCaller()
{
    var f = "myText.txt";
    var dates = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(f)
        .Where(l => l.Length > 6)) //At least...
    {
        var date = GetDate_value(line);

        if (date != null)
            dates.Add(date);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", dates));
}

public static string GetDate_value(string line)
{
    string output = null;

    if (line.StartsWith("Date:"))
    {
        output = line.Split(new[] { " " }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).LastOrDefault();

    }
    return output;
}
```

You could replace the above with just:

```cs
void TheCaller()
{
    var f = "myText.txt";
    var dates = File.ReadLines(f)
        .Where(l => l.StartsWith("Date: "))
        .Select(l => l.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .LastOrDefault()).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", dates));
}
```

The output of the given example is:

```
[12/23/23, 12/23/66, 12/25/67]
```